# Android: finish() of CountDownTimer is called even if cancel() is called

Tags: android, timer, countdown

I have used Countdown Timer like this

```
new CountDownTimer(15000, 15) {

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                 long seconds=millisUntilFinished/1000;
                 long min=millisUntilFinished%100;

                 timeleft=(int) (seconds*1000+min);
                 if(millisUntilFinished>=10000)
                 {
                     changeText.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                 }
                 else if(millisUntilFinished>=5000)
                 {
                     changeText.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA); 
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     changeText.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                 }
                 changeText.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds )+ "."+String.format("%02d", min )+" sec");

             }

             public void onFinish() {

                 timeleft=0;
                 missed++;
                  nametext.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                 nametext.setText("Time Up!");
                      bottombutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);   
                    globalflag=13;
                changeText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                changeText.setText("0.00 Sec");
                    Handler myHandler = new Handler();
                    myHandler.postDelayed(mMyRunnablecif, 3000);



             }
          }.start();
```

On a button click I have called `cancel()` but it stops counting for a while and then calls `onFinish()`. I need not to call `onFinish()` after calling `cancel()`. Is  there any solution for this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your `onClick` set a Boolean (buttonPressed for example) to true.

In your `onFinish` check this Boolean:

```
if (buttonPressed == true)
{
    //do nothing
}
else
{
    //run code
}
```

Comment: Does onFinish() recalls the acivity where it belongs to? or calls call back oncreate()

Comment: onFinish() with regards to countdown timer is not connected to the activity. It is just the method called when the countdown timer completes.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) instead and do something like this:

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // do your updates here
        mUpdateTimeHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

Handler mUpdateTimeHandler = new Handler();
mUpdateTimeHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
```

When cancelling the task:

```
mUpdateTimeHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also don't understand why the onFinish gets called despite calling cancel(). I guess the only workaround for this is to just null check your calls in onFinish to prevent any NPE's.

```
public void onFinish() {
   if (nametext == null || bottombutton == null || changeText == null || ... ) {
      return;
   }
...
```